# category not display in word press grammatically

Tags: php, functions, terms

I'm trying to create a new category in the taxonomy.php called '**USSERS**'. I have followed few examples online and got till this part.

```
function insert_term( $name,$tax,$parent='' ,$slug='') {
    $term_id = term_exists( $name, $tax);
    if ( !$term_id)
        $term_id = wp_insert_term( $name, $tax, array('parent'=>$parent,'slug'=>$ludg) );
    return $term_id;
}

insert_term('USSERS','category');
```

After doing the above code, i went to check the wordpress dashboard to see if I actually created the category but It doesn't show. So now i'm confused and lost because I have no idea how to proceed with the above code and make it show on the dashboard.

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar();
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
?>

function yourtheme_init() {
   insert_term('USSERS','category');
}
add_action('init', 'yourtheme_init');

function insert_term( $name,$tax,$parent='' ,$slug='') {
    $term_id = term_exists( $name, $tax);
    if ( !$term_id) {
        $term_id = wp_insert_term( $name, $tax, array('parent'=>$parent,'slug'=>$slug) );
    }
    return $term_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling this code? You need to add it to one of the init hooks.

If I add that to either a plugin or theme init, then it adds just fine for me, with the `$slug` typo corrected as Mike pointed out.

```
echo '<p>Debug: Loaded functions.php</p>';

function yourtheme_init() {
   echo '<p>Debug: called yourtheme_init</p>';
   insert_term('USSERS','category');
}
add_action('init', 'yourtheme_init');

function insert_term($name,$tax,$parent='', $slug='') {
    echo '<p>Debug: called insert_term</p>';
    $term_id = term_exists($name, $tax);
    if (!$term_id) {
        echo '<p>Debug: adding new term</p>';
        $term_id = wp_insert_term( $name, $tax, array('parent'=>$parent,'slug'=>$slug) );
        echo '<p>Debug: new term added with ID ' . $term_id . '</p>';
    } else {
       echo '<p>Debug: term already exists with ID ' . $term_id . '</p>';
    }

    die('<p>Debug: end</p>');
    return $term_id;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I added that code in taxomony.php. Which file should i be writing that in?

Comment: if I put this in category.php or category-template.php, it doesn't work. Please get back thank you.

Comment: It needs to be in your theme `functions.php` or in a custom plugin.

Comment: Check the update code for my themes functions.php. It doesn't really do anything.

Comment: So you need to try some debugging. Add a PHP `die("here");` in the code to see if it gets called. First add it to the top of the `functions.php` file to make sure the file is called. Then add it inside `yourtheme_init()` to check that the init hook is called. Then move it inside the `insert_term()` function to see if that is called. Also, inside `wp-config.php` make sure you have `WP_DEBUG` set to true to help catch any code errors.

Comment: Hey so after inserting die("here") on top of the functions file, it did work. The page only displayed "here" nothing else. However, when I copied the code u uploaded to functions file, the text would be visible on top of the website. Like, ("functions .... ...") and then the rest of the content. Am i suppose to change the yourtheme_init() ?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you've done. If you don't understand the PHP code and how to debug, then you may want to start a chant with me instead so that we can fix this issue. I've updated my answer with some more debugging. Use the new code instead - add it to the top of your` functions.php` file and then tell me the output of your page (or post a screenshot)

Comment: hey can you please message me so we can solve it

Comment: Sure, use this [chat link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92995/room-for-alex-holsgrove-and-ramazan)

Comment: i need 20 reputation

Comment: After chatting we have solved the problem. The code provided was working however the OP had other PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `$slug` as `$ludg`.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem.