# Return newly created category by code

Tags: php, functions

How would I return a category that I've just created. I need it to be under the current blog.

```
    <?php 
        $category = get_term_by('$first_name', '$value', 'category')
    ?>
```

the above code is taking me to site.com/authorFirstName-lastName

author not found

Comment: How did you create the category, what function you used? And "return a category" - return what? ID, slug, or?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336301/category-not-display-in-word-press-grammatically/336308?noredirect=1#comment494954_336308

Comment: I've used that function to create the category. And return the author of the post

Comment: Okay, so you're using your custom `insert_term` function? But I still don't quite understand what actually are you trying to do. And in the question, what are the `$first_name` and `$value`? They're also not supposed to be single-quoted. Can you update the question with the full code which defines those two variables?

Comment: Can we take this to chat please?

Comment: Well, I don't think your current reputation allows you to *talk* in chat.. after all, your question needs more details.

Comment: I've another account which we can talk to

Comment: In that case, you can invite me to chat via that account. And the first message would be the answers to the questions in my second comment.

Comment: its not letting me chat with you :)

Comment: Does the "new" answer help? It's not exactly the same like the previous answer.